# WebView is not able to open some https URL. Showing blank white screen

Tags: android, web

I have tested my app with many https URLs, almost all are working fine but not the one I want. I have tested my URL, it's working fine with all the browser except Internet Explorer.

1. Already handling SSL Error
2. Override shouldOverrideUrlLoading too.
3. webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

I want to know whether it's the problem in the URL or from Android.

Comment: First check if those urls have the same issue on default browser.

Comment: URL is not working with Internet Explorer. Rest in all the browsers working perfectly. What do you mean by default browser here?

Comment: Any browser other than one made by you is enough. Since it's not working in IE there must be an issue with your URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved my problem by enabling DomStorage.

```
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

I have searched about domStorage, as i understand it works if website using HTML5. Don't know too much about dom storage.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to ignore SSL, check below snippet.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
private WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

    };
```

Comment: Just check what error you are getting *SslError error*

Comment: That's what I am thinking, but URL is working fine with all the browsers except Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable javascript on the webview?

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, its the problem in the URL not with the Android. As you are saying there is no SSL certificate issue and all other https URL's are working except yours.
You should contact your service provider or check from web end.